# Calculating the connection count of a network

Tags: java, recursion

The question is to calculate the connection count of a fully connected mesh topology network. The total number of connections can be calculated with the formula (n x (n-1)) / 2. We are to implement the public class ConnectionCount method recursively and everything else was given to us. The problem is that I can't get it to compile. I am trying to figure out how to call the method on later so that the program will compile but I'm very confused. Please help, this is what I have so far:

```
public class ConnectionCount {
private int n;

public int ConnectionCalc(int n){

if(n > 0){
    return(n-1) + ConnectionCalc(n-1);
    return ConnectionCalc(n);
}
else{
    return 0;
}
}   

public static int connectionCount(int n)
{
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("connectionCount(" + i + ") returns " + connectionCount(i));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should have posted the error message.

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to this board and didn't think to do that. I most certainly will in the future, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the second return in that code. It's unreachable, as the compiler is undoubtedly telling you.

Comment: I did that and while it now compiles, each connectionCount returns 0. I can't change the rest of the code since that was part of the original problem, so I guess my question is how do I implement the ConnectionCalc method into the rest of the program?